# Accessing attributes per element in list

Tags: r, for-loop, attributes

I would like to use attributes to store variable names like Stata does with their labels: Instead of e.g. printing the variable name (to e.g. output tables), I'd rather have attribute thereof (hence I call the attribute `name`). But how can I access it in a loop?

```
dummies <- c("a", "b", "c")
attr(dummies, "names") <- c("First letter", "Second letter", "Third letter")

for (dummy in dummies) {
  # do something with dummy
  # e.g. accessing a variable in a dataframe
  # and printing something to a table
  print attr(dummies$dummy, "names") # doesn't work
  print attr(dummies, "names")$dummy # doesn't work
}
```

As an alternative approach one can use a matrix:

dummies <- c("a", "b", "c")
names <- c("First letter", "Second letter", "Third letter")
dummies.matrix <- matrix(c(dummies, names), nrow=3)

Then I loop over `dummies.matrix`:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(dummies.matrix)) {
  print(dummies.matrix[i,1]) # value
  print(dummies.matrix[i,2]) # name or label
}
```

But that's neither convenient nor intuitive.

Comment: Try `attr(dummies[[dummy]], "names")`

Comment: or `for ( i in 1 : length( dummies ) ) print( attr( dummies[ i ], "name" ) )`

Comment: @Andrie: `subscript out of bounds`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have an indexing problem.

```
dummies <- c("a", "b", "c")
attr(dummies, "names") <- c("First letter", "Second letter", "Third letter")

for (i in seq_along(dummies)) {
  print(dummies[i])
  print(attr(dummies[i], "names"))
}
```

As a style point, be cautious about using indexes like `dummy` on vectors named `dummies`.  At some point the vector and the index start to blend together, which makes it harder to interpret what the code should be doing.

Comment: So, it's not possible to use the elements of `dummies` as index? I need the detour over `i`?

Comment: You _could_ if you use `for (i in dummies)` and then `print(i)` and `print(attr(dummies[dummies == i], "names"))`.  But that's pretty much the same think, takes longer to get there, and is harder to read (in my opinion).